# Compare Similarity Between Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, similarity

I am trying to find an efficient way to compare a given array that represents the Quality of Service of a Client with the QOS of a Two Web Services and pick up the most similar to the given QOS.

```
  int[] arrayCompare(int[] clientQOS){

      int[] service1QOS=new int[]{3,1,4};
      int[] service2QOS=new int[]{1,3,3};

      //I want to compare clientQOS     with  S1 QOS       and S2 QOS

      return  mostSimilarArray
   }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Client QOS values can vary from 0-5  so it can be something like (3,5,2) it has no weighted values.

Comment: Have a look at near duplicate detection based on hashes - it is highly efficient.

Comment: What is the expected output? I mean what should the method return.

Comment: @Grrrrr as you can see in the statement of the method its int[].The most similar Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the source array for each target, incrementing a counter by the delta (positive difference between the values). The smallest delta sum is the closest match.

Caveats

This should be true if you consider numerically closer to be more similar, and the scale between different values are equal.

Comment: Nice,i think that should work fine :) i dont need something more complex as i could use a small database to give me the most similar WebService given a clientQOS

Comment: The method you described is called Manhattan distance :) Thank you that you reminded me

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a custom object instead of array and implement interface Comparable. This way you can encapsulate algorithm of comparison and reuse it later in other places.

Comment: When u say algorithm of comparison ? Isn't it what i am looking for in the first place ?

Comment: Right you are. First you need to encapsulate it. Than you can follow TDD practice and create an "obvious implementation". Example of obvious implementation: number of numbers that are similar in both arrays. As long as your question can have several correct answers, encapsulation can allow to use several heuristics together in bounds of one JVM.

Comment: I think this method is great for objects more complicated than an Array with ints but i think i catch the point about the "several correct answers" Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of method for calculate array "similarity".

Here the Golang implementation:

```golang
// SimilarityPreCheck is delegated to verify that the given array have the correct size
func SimilarityPreCheck(a, b []float64) bool {
    if len(a) == 0 || len(b) == 0 {
        log.Println("CosineSimilarity | Nil input data")
        return false
    }

    if len(a) != len(b) {
        log.Printf("CosineSimilarity | Input vectors have different size")
        return false
    }

    return true
}

// CosineSimilarity is delegated to calculate the Cosine Similarity for the given array
func CosineSimilarity(a, b []float64) float64 {
    if !SimilarityPreCheck(a, b) {
        return -1
    }

    // Calculate numerator
    var numerator float64
    for i := range a {
        numerator += a[i] * b[i]
    }

    // Caluclate first term of denominator
    var den1 float64
    for i := range a {
        den1 += math.Pow(a[i], 2)
    }
    den1 = math.Sqrt(den1)

    // Caluclate second term of denominator
    var den2 float64
    for i := range b {
        den2 += math.Pow(b[i], 2)
    }
    den2 = math.Sqrt(den2)

    result := numerator / (den1 * den2)
    return result
}

// EuclideanDistance is delegated to calculate the euclidean distance for the given array
func EuclideanDistance(v1, v2 []float64) float64 {
    if !SimilarityPreCheck(v1, v2) {
        return -1
    }
    var euclidean float64
    for i := range v1 {
        euclidean += math.Pow(v1[i]-v2[i], 2)
    }
    return math.Sqrt(euclidean)
}

// ManhattanDistance is delegated to calculate the Manhattan norm for the given array
func ManhattanDistance(v1, v2 []float64) float64 {
    if !SimilarityPreCheck(v1, v2) {
        return -1
    }
    var taxicab float64
    for i := range v1 {
        taxicab += math.Abs(v2[i] - v1[i])
    }
    return taxicab
}
```